# Adding page subdirectory dynamically, as like buddypress does

Tags: wp-query

I have a page with slug/name **charts**. So the url looks like `http://domain.tld/charts/` for the Charts page. When i type the url to `http://domain.tld/charts/(something)` or `http://domain.tld/charts/(something)/(something)`, i got error not found, logically it should as there is no sub page with the given names.

Now what is want is, when is visit to `http://domain.tld/charts/(something)` or `http://domain.tld/charts/(something)/(something)`, it should still query the Charts page, and also add the single or multiple occurred `(something)` into wp query var so that i can access it with get_query_var function. The (something) would return as an array ofcourse.

The `(something)` could be any Alphanumeric characters, and not needed to be a valid one. Just need it so that WordPress Still makes query for the Chart page, and all the extra url path are added to wp_query Object.

Your help is strongly needed.

Comment: Have a look at [`add_rewrite_rule` questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-rewrite-rule) and [in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse128082_add_rewrite_rule');
function wpse128082_add_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array(
        '^charts/(.*)' => 'index.php?pagename=charts&something='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse128082_add_query_var');
function wpse128082_add_query_var($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'something';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

On your *Charts* page, you can access the new query var with `get_query_var('something')`.

Comment: I suggest adding rewrite rules via the API: [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).